# How to set an image with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How do I set an image that is returned from a function?

```
struct RearKeyCard: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: generateBarcode(from: "Steve Jobs")!)
            .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.gray/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .font(.custom("Baskerville", size: 15.0))
    }
}

func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: self.generateBarcode(from: "Steve Jobs"))
        .background(Color.gray)
        .font(.custom("Baskerville", size: 15.0))
        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width:3, height: 3))
}
func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage {
    let data = string.data(using: .ascii)
    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let output = filter.outputImage {
             if let cgimg = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
             }
         }
    }
    return UIImage()
}
}
```